# ios: center vertically not working inside UIContainerView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, center, uicontainerview

I want to programatically center a view both vertically and horizontally inside a UIContinerView. So i tried..

```
UIView view = new UIView(new CGRect(0,0,100,100));
view.Center = new CGPoint(controller.View.Bounds.GetMidX(), controller.View.Bounds.GetMidY());
view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
controller.View.AddSubview(view)
```

But this is what I get (in the screenshot below) clearly it is not center vertical. ContainerView is the area below the TabBar to  the bottom of the screen. Without a ContainerView the above code works.

I tried adding constrains center vertical and horizontal in storyboard. then it works but not programaticlly... please help

[image]

I also tried:

```
CGPoint center = view.Center;
center.X = controller.View.Center.X;
center.Y = controller.View.Center.Y;
view.Center = center;
```

but same effect

Comment: If you are calling it in `viewDidLoad`, then the size of the view is probably not the final one. I would suggest either using constraints, or setting the center in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.Center = new CGPoint(controller.View.Bounds.GetMidX(), controller.View.Bounds.GetMidY() - TabBarHeight / 2);
```

or

```
view.Center = containterView.center
containterView.AddSubview(view)
```

Comment: I'm passing a reference of of the ViewController to another function. That why I've added controller.View

Comment: if you are doing `View.AddSubview(view)`, center should be the `View`'a center

Comment: Well, it was a mistake I made while editing the code for creating this topic. I've corrected now.

Comment: @HeisenBerg I can only suggest. did you try `view.Center = controller.View.center`? Is viewController's view fully initialized? did you try print the values?